# Random Double in given range including [-MAX_VALUE,MAX_VALUE]

Tags: java

How do I implement a function `getRandomDouble(min,max)` which is able to handle `+-Double.MAX_VALUE`as parameter?

**Online Research:**

Most answers to this question are:

```
public Double getRandomDouble(double min, double max) {
    return min + (max-min)*Random.nextDouble(); 
}
```

This works fine if `min` and `max` are not `+-Double.MAX_VALUE`. If so, `max-min` is out of range or infinity. Changing the parameters to `BigDecimal` solves this issue, but the result is always a double with 50 zeros and no decimals. This is the result of a very large number (`2*MAX_VALUE`) multiplied a double between [0,1] with only a view decimals.

So, I found a solution for `+-MAX_VALUE` like this:

```
public double getRandomDouble() {
    while(true) {
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(Random.nextLong());
        if (d < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY && d > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
            return d;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but does not consider other bounds.

How can I combine both approaches to get random double in a given range that's maybe `+-MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: Genuine question: what on earth are you doing where it is important that the input values straddle the very edges of the Double type?

Comment: Neuro-quantum physics... just kidding. In our application the default values are `+-MAX_VALUE` if no bounds have been specified. And NO, changing the default values is not an option. This may solve my problem temporary, but I would like to have a solution which still works if in one month a colleague switches back the settings :-)

Comment: That doesn't explain what these numbers are used for, and so doesn't explain why you need Double's full fidelity when typically Math.random() yields a number between 0 and 1 that is already vastly higher fidelity than you can invent use cases to toggle. Wanting reliable RNG over the full Double range can make sense, but _almost never does_ so anyone who's ever had to maintain code will probably want to know why you need these rather than writing overly inefficient code for dealing with the edge case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working only with the max values, I think I have a solution.

Mathematically it should be the same:

You produce 2 random numbers and sum them up. Each number should be between `-maxValue / 2` and `+maxValue / 2`. That way the sum will be a random number between `-maxValue` and `+maxValue`.

```
public Double getRandomDouble(double min, double max) {
    double halfMin = min/2;
    double halfMax = max/2;
    double sum = halfMin + (halfMax-halfMin)*Random.nextDouble(); 
    return sum + (halfMin + (halfMax-halfMin)*Random.nextDouble());
}
```

Comment: Does this approach result in a bias towards the "middle"? Sounds like the board game "Catan".

Comment: This solves has the same issues like the simple one. It can get an overflow (result > MAX_VALUE) and will have also always 50 zeros and no decimals. Ok, maybe 49 zeros because of the /2.

Comment: @Progman No I don't think so, because if it's a random number you can get both numbers as `-maxValue/2` and the sum of them would be `-maxValue`. Same goes for `+maxValue` and every other value between `-maxValue` and `+maxValue`

Comment: @Thanthla it won't get overflow because in this case `halfMax-halfMin` will be `+maxValue` (no overflow), and result can be like you described in the question

Comment: @Thanthla and in this solution you don't need to use `BigDecimal` so you don't have to deal with the 50 zeros

Comment: @OmriAttiya I think, there is a bias. As an example there are way more combinations on how to get to zero (-1+1,-1.4+1.4,+3.9-3.9,...), but there is only one combination on how to get to `MIN_VALUE` (`MIN_VALUE/2`+`MIN_VALUE/2`).

Comment: You are right, it has no overflow. But the zeros are still there. As I said, it is not a problem of `BigDecimal`but of multiplying `MAX_VALUE` with a number, which has not so many decimals. This solution will never generate a number like 0.1.

Comment: @Progman I agree that there are more combinations to create zero value, but since it's a **random** value, there should not be a bias.

Comment: @Thanthla in order to solve your decimal places problem, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153785/3729184) solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by drawing two `double` random numbers. The first one is used to decide if you want a negative value or a positive value. The second one is used for the actual value from the negative part or the positive part. The approach will be like this:

Calculate the quotient between the range from zero to upper bound and the range from zero to lower bound. This will get you the information like "40% the value is positive, 60% the value is negative". Use the first random number to check which it is.

Then when you know if it is negative or positive use the normal approach to get a random number between zero and the lower/upper bound. This value can only be between `0` and `MAX_VALUE` (or `MIN_VALUE`), so there will be no "overflow".

However, I don't know about the combined probability in this case, if it is the same random probability when drawing only one random `double` value. If you have a negative/positive split of about 5% and 95%, then the second random number will be hit a value inside the 5% or the 95%. Not sure if it still "random" or if it even creates unwanted bias.